# Can you use a USB to expand the Xbox's storage?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 4GB, and I just bought GTA V, but it needs 8GB.  Can I use a USB or hard drive to use its storage so I don't need to buy a new Xbox?

Comment: You can. But be warned, you cannot allocate more than 32GB or so of usable space on the drive, otherwise the Xbox will not recognize the partition.

Comment: In my personal experience, the XBox formatting is fairly bulky too.  I once tried using a small key to store some XBL Arcade games to make some space on one of my boxes, and after formatting there was basically no space on the key.  I believe it was 1 GB.  After that I just bit the bullet and bought a licensed expansion drive.

Answer (score 5):

You can expand your storage space.

The stick must be formatted to the xbox file system and can be then only used on the xbox, also the maximum possible size is 32GB. To format the usb stick:

1. Plug in stick
2. Press th Guide button and go to Settings tab and select System settings
3. Select storage
4. Select USB storage
5. Click configure now
6. Move the reserved storage slider you your wanted level, preferably use the 
   wholestick. Note that 512Mb of your stick is used for xbox system files so 
   it cannot be used to save game data. (So for gta you should get a 16GB stick,
   8GB isn't enough.
7. All done, you can now save your GTA to the stick

Guide adapted from [xbox support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a 32GB USB stick by just plugging it in and then going to the storage options in the system preference area and formatting it for use with the Xbox. Be warned that after doing this, you can't use it on regular PC's without reformatting it.

Any larger than 32GB and it only allows you to use 32GB for games, and the rest will be allocated to video/image files (or not recognized, I forget).

Furthermore, you don't need to buy a new Xbox if you want to get more storage space. You can just purchase a 320GB hard drive and plug it in on the top (there's either a panel that you can remove if its a slim or the hard drive is connected on top if you own the older white Xboxs). Be warned that if you choose to do this, you will most probably need to do a content transfer which will require an additional cable.

Answer (score 4):

You can.
But you must format this USB to use it for the XBox. So you can use it only for the XBox.

And the maximum space of the USB is 32GB! So do not use bigger USB's.